# JAX-RS with JSON

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have setup a webservice with JAX-RS and Resteasy. The GET request is working but when I send a JSON-Request via POST, I am getting a `415 Unsupported Media Type` error message. 
Following code shows my current implementation:

```
@Path("ws")
public class YagiSolverWebservice
{
    @GET
    public String hello()
    {
        return "HELLO!";
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void solveGrid(Test test)
    {
        System.out.println("Test: " + test);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I am testing the Webserive with POSTMAN as chrome plugin. The following header is produced, in the chrome request:

> ```
> POST /YagiSolver/ws HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Length: 34
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.132 Safari/537.36
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
> Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
> ```

Comment: What content-type are you sending in your POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your `Accept` and `Content-Types` headers and it has to be `application/json`.
Because your service consumes only `json`.

```
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to give the mime type in @Consumes

The value of @Consumes is an array of String of acceptable MIME types. For example:

```
@Consumes({"text/plain,text/html"})
```

The following example shows how to apply @Consumes at both the class and method levels:

```
@Path("/myResource")
@Consumes("multipart/related")
public class SomeResource {
    @POST
    public String doPost(MimeMultipart mimeMultipartData) {
        ...
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public String doPost2(FormURLEncodedProperties formData) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can read more about it in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giepu/index.html

Comment: His @Consumes is correct, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON translates to the string "application/json"